# KeyCode field in custom inspector

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a custom inspector for my script, and I have an option to pick a KeyCode as you can see below

[image: key]

However, now that I'm using a custom inspector, I don't know how to add a Keycode Field.
I *assumed* it would be like the rest of the custom objects, where you would just use `EditorGUILayout.ObjectField()` but since KeyCode doesn't derive from `UnityEngine.Object` it doesn't work.

I've tried researching, but all I can find are posts on how to detect keypresses in the custom inspector.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Since KeyCode is an enumeration, did you try using an [EnumPopup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup.html)?

Comment: That's a shout actually, Ill try that now.

Comment: Yes, it works, thankyou, I just had to make sure I had the correct cast: _defaultInteractionKey = (KeyCode)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Default Interaction Key", _defaultInteractionKey);

Comment: If you've solved your problem, be sure to post the code that worked for you as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you can just use a cast along with an EnumPopup, like this:

```
_defaultInteractionKey = (KeyCode)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Default Interaction Key", _defaultInteractionKey);
```